# std::set_intersection and iterators

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, iterator, std

Is it possible to have the output of `std::set_intersection` or other `std::set_*` algorithmic functions be added directly to a type `std::set`?

So far, I can only think of a way to add directly to something that allows `std::back_inserter`.

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   // sorted so ok for set operations
   set<int> s = { 2, 3, 1 };
   set<int> s2 = { 1 };
   vector<int> v;

   set_intersection(s.begin(), s.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),
      back_inserter(v));

   copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ","));
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, You can use [`std::inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter), instead of the `std::back_inserter` like this.

```
#include <iterator> // std::inserter

std::set<int> s3;
std::set_intersection(s.begin(), s.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),
      std::inserter(s3, s3.end()));
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Does using `s3.end()` as the second argument maintain the `s3` will remain correctly ordered?

Comment: @notaorb Yes, it will. Here is a demo: https://godbolt.org/z/3vGjxG

Comment: Do you know if `set_*` commands will work on an `unordered_set`?  My suspicion is *no* because the documents state the container must  be ordered.

Comment: @notaorb Correct.

Comment: `std::set_intersection`, `std::set_difference`, `std::set_symmetric_difference`, `std::set_union`.

Comment: @JeJo I was considering the case of using same `<algorithm>` `set_*` functions on a `<unordered_set>` and if they would work.  A response above indicates they would not, because the `unordered_set` is not sort ordered.

Comment: I wonder, what is the time complexity of this approach? It seems that the hint passed by `std::inserter` to `std::set::insert` will be wrong starting from the second insertion. But then the standard says that each insertion takes `O(log N)` time, which gives `O(N log N)` complexity. Is this correct? If yes, this is unfortunate.

Comment: @Evg If my benchmark is correct, it is not `O(N lof N)` : https://godbolt.org/z/xqo647, but definitely more than normal `std::set::insert`ion.

Comment: Thanks. I missed `++iter;` here: [`std::insert_iterator::operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator/operator%3D). With `++iter` it is indeed `O(N)`. Curiously, if I [use my own inserter](https://godbolt.org/z/o7h9YT) that always inserts just before `end()`, it is ~4 times faster than `std::inserter(s, s.end())` on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just use `inserter` instead of `back_inserter`

```
set<int> s = {2, 3, 1};
set<int> s2 = {1};
set<int> s3;

set_intersection(s.begin(), s.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),
         inserter(s3, s3.end()));
```

Comment: Doesn't this function require 2 arguments?

Comment: I tried `inserter(s3, s3.begin())` but not sure if that would change the ordering of the set?

Comment: @notaorb Yes apologies, I've updated the answer. When used with a set the second argument is only used as a hint for the insertion position, so it doesn't matter what that value is.

Comment: @notaorb See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator/operator%3D for details.